# Rails csv parsing - find by vs limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, activerecord

Ok, so I'm trying to export CSVs within my application but every time I try to find the records I want to export through the Activerecord find_by method, the csv is inputted with ActiveRecord Relations instead of the data that I'm trying to show.

For example, when I do this:

```
@Products = Product.find_by(:name => @name)
```

I get back lots of these in the CSV:

```
#<Product:0x007ff0d234cef0>,#<Product:0x007ff0d6922ad8>
```

However if I do this:

```
Products = Product.limit(100)
```

The CSV shows exactly as it should. What can I do to query active-record by a certain attribute to get back a relation to display in my csv?

P.S

I'm following this really simple tutorial: https://www.codementor.io/victor_hazbun/export-records-to-csv-files-ruby-on-rails-vda8323q0

*Edit - here's the controller code I'm using to generate the csv:*

```
   def export
@products = []
@names = params[:nameselected].split(',').map(&:strip)
@names.each{|name|
  name = name.slice!(0)
  @products.push(Product.find_by(:name => name)
}
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv { send_data @products.to_csv }
  format.xls
end
```

end

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
  csv.add_row column_names
  all.each do |foo|
    values = foo.attributes.values
    csv.add_row values
  end
end
```

end

I take in a list of product names that users select with Javascript and then I want to generate them into a CSV. I could just create a CSV in Javascript but I want to make them shareable in the future too.

Comment: Can you add the code you're using to generate the CSV? we can't tell you why code isn't working as you'd expect without seeing what code you're running

Comment: @SimpleLime Done it - appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You create a `@products` variable of type array

```
@products = []
@products.class 
=> Array
```

so when you do

```
format.csv { send_data @products.to_csv }
```

It will create a `csv` for every element of the Array.

When you do a Query on the `Product` model

```
@Products = Product.find_by(:name => @name)
@Products.class 
=> Product
```

You will return an object of class `Product::ActiveRecord_Relation`

So you need to perform a query like this:

```
names = ['firstname', 'secondname', 'thirdname']
Product.where(name: names)
```

To find more info you should read the following guides to write the query as you like

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions

http://api.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: @Зелёный `<Product:0x007ff0d234cef0>` is just the `@products.class.to_s`

so the problem is in his `self.to_csv` method

Comment: @Зелёный I am quoting him `@Products = Product.find_by(:name => @name)` and `find_by` returns one object not an `Product::ActiveRecord_Relation` but he wrote the post with some incorrections. He does not mean `@Products` but `@product` the point is the problem is in `self.to_csv` which is returning to him the value to string of his array instead of the fields of those objects distributed by rows and columns`#<Product:0x007ff0d234cef0>,#<Product:0x007ff0d6922ad8>`
more details are included in the above link